# Beautifulsoup django integration

Tags: django, python-2.7, beautifulsoup

still a newbie so I have a bunch of questions which might seem silly. However, here I go:

as a project to learn python, I decided I would start with something simple. The idea I had was to go to craigslist and find the prices of motorcycles, go through the first 10 pages of each city and give a mean, median and price trends. the result of that work can be found here (http://craigslistcompanion.co.nf/) as well as the codes.

now in order to make things better i decided that i should let the user input what they want (motorcycle/ car/ bikes) and from where (sfbay/ austin etc) and get the same results as shown in that page. as i started looking into it i was told that learning django would be a good place to start and i have been trying to do that for the last couple of days. however, what i have learn so far is mostly setting up databases and handling them.

I was wondering if there is a tutorial somewhere which will show me how to take input from the user and then manipulate it. i want to do this completely using python/ django.

for example lets say i want the user to input their first and last name and then try to play with that string and output something. how would i go about doing that?

thanks

Comment: those operation can be made using javascript, why dont free your server, and let it only provide the variables, then use the client side to manipulate them?

Comment: if we are using django for example i understand that i get the input through forms, then send that user request through views for a response. but how do i actually manipulate the request and work on that input through python scripts?

Comment: when a user will send the form, then the form is splitted to variables, then what you have to do is just treat that variable as string, in `tornado` (another framework) when you make `name = self.get_argument("fname")` what you'll do is just get `name` and play with it as a string, `name.upper()`..etc

Comment: my knowledge of coding is very limited. as i started with python and liked its ease of use as well as active and helpful user community i would like to get proficient in it before trying to learn something like javascript.

Comment: when i started, i choose Django, but switched to Tornado to its ease of use, but the  principe is the same, you feed a varible, and then you play it, as a type, i always  use `print type(variable)` to see which type it is, then i choose what to do (make the upper case for example), or i print a variable in a console when there is error (since python is a script and each line is evaluated so you can get the variable before the error) by using `print variable`

Comment: me too am a beginner, so to learn javascript i just use some limited functions, and i learn them using the autocompletion of Chrome developper tool console, you get just type `document` you add the dot, and voila! because as a rule, try to free your server from some calculation, if you can do it using javascript (like formatting) then it will be better to delegate this work to your browser, i'm really sorry if i cant help in django, but if you want basic ideas am here, i use tornado, but both are python ;)

Comment: cool i will look up tornado tonight,thanks

Comment: tornado is a framework that includes a server, and it is asynchronous (this is where you struggle), but for simple  application where the user asks for a forms, it is really simple! i choosed tornado because i run the  file as a normal python file, in Django i must do some basic steps and it dident fit to my logic. you have also Flask which is a small framework if you are seeking for  other fully WSGI solutions (that will put under Apache)

Answer (score 1):

First some clarification. Do you want to develop a web interface for your users? If so, then Django is a great start. [The Django Book](http://www.djangobook.com/en/2.0/index.html) is a very good introduction to Django and teaches you with examples. The task of getting user information, validating it, manipulating it and saving it in a database is the most basic of task and it is explained well in the book.

The next thing is web scraping craigslist. From how you structured your question, it seams that you have solved that part of the problem. right?

Comment: yes...i have been able to scrape data from websites using beautifulsoup. however, what i want to do is just take an input from the user and pass it to the python code to run it and show the results.

Comment: You have everything you need from chapter 1 to 7. This will help you with the basic structure of your web application. I would guess that it would take you a day to understand the basics. I'm hoping it would be enough to help you solve the interface part of you application.